# "Error allocating I/O BAR for PCI device" when booting Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory, pci, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error allocating Mem BAR for PCI Device 0X/00/0.](https://superuser.com/questions/1117/error-allocating-mem-bar-for-pci-device-0x-00-0)

I have a Dell Optiplex 380. When I try to boot Windows 7 normally I get the following after the Windows loading screen:

```
*** Hardware Malfuncion

Call your hardware vendor for support

NMI: Parity Check / Memory Parity Error

*** The system has halted ***
```

When I boot in recovery mode I get the following:

```
Status: 0xc000000e

Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

Finally when boot from a CD, for a few seconds the screen displays this:

```
03/00/0: Error allocating I/O BAR for PCI device
03/00/0: Error allocating I/O BAR for PCI device
```

I'm hoping for more insight into the meaning of that final "I/O BAR" error. Anybody know what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As answered once before on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1194), [the Dell documentation](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/pe430sc/en/it/x9719c20.htm#wp1054081) tells you [the procedure for troubleshooting expansion cards](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/pe430sc/en/it/x9719c40.htm#wp1055045).

Comment: The question referred to here pertains to "Error allocating *Mem* BAR for PCI Device". The in error question is about *I/O*

Comment: … and the Dell documentation, as you would know had you followed the hyperlink in the above answer and read it, covers both messages (and indeed several more besides that have the same pattern).

Comment: Turns out it was the wireless network card. Took it out and the computer works fine now.

Comment: Is there a new link that could be had (for this information)? I'd like to have a look myself...